# How to disable intel GPU on boot without using BIOS

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, bootloader, hybrid-graphics

I have a Pavilion dv6-3182ea laptop with an ATI/Intel hybrid graphics, and I would like to know if it is possible to switch the Intel GPU off when Ubuntu 11.10 boots, I have tried to mess around with vgaswitcheroo however the FGLRX driver removes the folder making any switching impossible.

I require the ATI card with FGLRX drivers because I am trying to see how one of my games runs through wine, but either my Intel GPU or ATI one without FGLRX will not run the game, this has been annoying my for awhile now and I really want to get it fixed.

I have come across this piece of code to add to the grub config which switches all GPUs on, activates the integrated GPU then switches the discrete one off:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modeset=1 hybridopts=ON,IGD,OFF"
```

I was wondering if it is possible to modify this to switch to and activate the discrete GPU to allow me to use the FGLRX drivers, using them otherwise stops my system booting because xorg.conf is not correct for the integrated GPU to work and prevents the xserver running.

I am unable to do this in the BIOS because HP do not think we should be allowed this basic feature.